# C++ Overwrite initializer list in unit test

Tags: c++, googletest

I have some C++ code like this that I want to unit test:

```
class Example
{
    private: 
        ExpensiveObject expensiveObject;
        
    public:
        Example() : expensiveObject() {
            ... constructor code
        }

        methodA() {
            ... some code
        }
}
```

To write a unit test for `methodA` I need to create an instance of `Example`. The problem is that I don't want to initialize `expensiveObject`, I would want to set it to null in my unit test (I am using Google Test). Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Values can't be null. At all. If you want it to be nullable, use `std::optional` or a smart pointer. This is C++, not Java.

Comment: To me, sounds like you need to change the code to use *dependency injection*.  Instead of having `Example` construct its own `ExpensiveObject`, have that be passed in as a constructor parameter: `Example(std::unique_ptr<ExpensiveObject> eo) : expensiveObject(move(eo)) {}`.  If ExpensiveObject is an *interface*, your unit tests can construct a mock object that implements the portion of the interface your unit test cares about.

Comment: Is it possible to modify `ExpensiveObject`? Would it be possible to replace the class definition with a template class + a type alias? In the former case you could e.g. create an additional constructor for `ExpensiveObject` that receives a tag that makes it skip any expensive initializations and create a private inline constructor for `Example` using that constructor adding a friend in the tests that is able to use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`expensiveObject` cannot be assigned `null`. What you might want is to have a smart pointer to `ExpensiveObject`, and have multiple constructors or better you want to inject your dependencies.

```
class Example
{
    private: 
        std::shared_ptr<ExpensiveObject> expensiveObject;
        
    public:
        Example(std::shared_ptr<ExpensiveObject> ptr) : expensiveObject(ptr) {
            //... constructor code
        }

        methodA() {
            //... some code
        }
}
```

Now you can test it for null scenarios as well

```
Example ex{nullptr};
ex.methodA();
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any way to do this without slightly modifying the definition of the `Example` class. However, if you can tolerate to do this, there are several ways to do this: dependency injection using pointers as the other answer mentioned, or templatizing the class as shown below:

```cpp
// Used for production.
class ExpensiveObject {
  // Expensive stuff here
};

// Only used for testing.
class CheapObject {
  // Cheap stuff here
};

// Instantiate with ExpensiveObject for production and with CheapObject for
// testing.
template <class T>
class Example {
 private:
  T expensiveObject;

 public:
  Example() : expensiveObject() {}

  int methodA() { return 1; }
};

TEST(Example, Test1) {
  // CheapObject is used for testing.
  Example<CheapObject> example;
  EXPECT_EQ(example.methodA(), 1);
}
```

Live example: https://godbolt.org/z/7e1rhWY4b